# what happens if I write String s1= "java"; String s2= s1+ "world";?

Tags: java, string

Please tell me that What actually happens in memory area if

```
String st1= "java";  
String st2= St1+ "world";
```

and if Write

```
String st1= new String("java");
```

then where object will be created and where this "java" will be stored. will it create two object or will it create two memory space ?

Comment: @VirginiaM1203-- ok, According to you the st1 will be replaced by it's value "java" and concatenation will take place after that new object creation. that's it.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/j3d_string.html) should answer your question. In your first example, st1 and st2 would be part of the string common pool. In the string common pool, two string objects with the same contents share the same memory space. Strings are immutable, so st2 will not be in the same space as st1 and will not modify st1.

In your second example, the new operator and string constructor create an object in the heap. Strings in the heap each have their own memory space, even if they have the same contents.